# Datatype <dtype_unknown> is not supported for sorting operation

Tags: sql, firebird

Доброго времени суток.
Был запрос:

```
SELECT
  t1.PV_FISH_ID,
  t1.PV_FISH_NAME,
  t1.PV_ACOUNT,
  min(t1.PV_MIN_WEIGHT),
  t1.PV_ATROF,
  (SELECT SUM(PV_FISH_COUNT) FROM PlanView WHERE PV_FISH_ID = t1.PV_FISH_ID AND PV_ATROF>=PV_MIN_WEIGHT),
  max(t1.PV_MAX_WEIGHT),
  max(t1.PV_CREDIT_WEIGHT) AS CREDIT
FROM PlanView t1
LEFT JOIN PlanView t2 ON t1.PV_FISH_ID=t2.PV_FISH_ID
WHERE t2.PV_MIN_WEIGHT < t2.PV_ATROF AND t2.PV_MAX_WEIGHT > t2.PV_ATROF AND t2.PV_ATROF>=t2.PV_MIN_WEIGHT
AND
t2.PV_UD=1
AND
t2.PV_N=1
AND t2.PV_THROUGH=-1
GROUP BY t1.PV_FISH_ID, t1.PV_FISH_NAME, t1.PV_ACOUNT, t1.PV_ATROF;
```

И пока `PlanView` был таблицей всё работало, но переделал я его на `View` и получил эту ошибку, как от неё избавиться?
И, если не сложно, помогите оптимизировать этот запрос, сдаётся мне он очень не оптимальный.

Код ViewPlan:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW PLANVIEW(
    PV_ID,
    PV_FISH_ID,
    PV_FISH_NAME,
    PV_MIN_WEIGHT,
    PV_MAX_WEIGHT,
    PV_ATROF,
    PV_ACOUNT,
    PV_PRICE,
    PV_FISH_COUNT,
    PV_CREDIT_WEIGHT,
    PV_CREDIT,
    PV_OPYT,
    PV_THROUGH,
    PV_N,
    PV_U,
    PV_D,
    PV_V,
    PV_UD,
    PV_DO,
    PV_SP)
AS
SELECT
  NF_ID, FL_FISH_ID,
  NF_NAME, PF_MIN_WEIGHT, PF_MAX_WEIGHT,
  AF_WTROF,
  AF_COUNT, PF_PRICE,
  FL_FISH_COUNT, PF_CREDIT_WEIGHT, PF_CREDIT,
  AF_OPYT, PF_THROUGH,
  (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM FishDaysTime WHERE FD_FISH_ID=FL_FISH_ID AND FD_DTIME_ID=0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM FishDaysTime WHERE FD_FISH_ID=FL_FISH_ID AND FD_DTIME_ID=1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM FishDaysTime WHERE FD_FISH_ID=FL_FISH_ID AND FD_DTIME_ID=2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM FishDaysTime WHERE FD_FISH_ID=FL_FISH_ID AND FD_DTIME_ID=3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM RodTable WHERE RT_ID=FL_FISH_ID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DonkeyTable WHERE DOT_FISH_ID=FL_FISH_ID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SpinTable WHERE ST_ID=FL_FISH_ID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM FishOnLocation, ParamsFish, NamesFish, AkkFishTable
WHERE FL_LOC_ID=76
AND PF_FISH_INDEX=NF_ID
AND FL_FISH_ID=PF_ID
AND AF_ID=NF_ID
```

Comment: Где код вьюхи PlanView ?

Comment: @Ivan, добавил. Вообще хотел сделать всё в 1 запросе в идеале, но не смог, потому разделил.

Answer (score 1):

По воводу оптимизации. Правда не запроса, а view
Предалагаю заменить штуки вида `(CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM FishDaysTime WHERE FD_FISH_ID=FL_FISH_ID AND FD_DTIME_ID=0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),`
на `LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 AS THE_ONE, FD_FISH_ID, FD_DTIME_ID FROM FishDaysTime) FDT0 ON (FD_FISH_ID=FL_FISH_ID AND FD_DTIME_ID=0)` + `COALESCE(FDT0.THE_ONE, 0)`
по нижеследующей схеме и посмотреть что будет. По крайней мере выгладит красивее, на мой взгляд.
И да, такаой способ работает, если подзапрос вернёт не более одной записи. Если больше, то надо поставить DISTINCT либо в подзапросы, либо в запрос.

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW PLANVIEW(
    PV_ID,
    PV_FISH_ID,
    PV_FISH_NAME,
    PV_MIN_WEIGHT,
    PV_MAX_WEIGHT,
    PV_ATROF,
    PV_ACOUNT,
    PV_PRICE,
    PV_FISH_COUNT,
    PV_CREDIT_WEIGHT,
    PV_CREDIT,
    PV_OPYT,
    PV_THROUGH,
    PV_N,
    PV_U,
    PV_D,
    PV_V,
    PV_UD,
    PV_DO,
    PV_SP)
AS
SELECT
  NF_ID, FL_FISH_ID,
  NF_NAME, PF_MIN_WEIGHT, PF_MAX_WEIGHT,
  AF_WTROF,
  AF_COUNT, PF_PRICE,
  FL_FISH_COUNT, PF_CREDIT_WEIGHT, PF_CREDIT,
  AF_OPYT, PF_THROUGH,
  COALESCE(FDT0.THE_ONE, 0),
  COALESCE(FDT1.THE_ONE, 0),
  ...
FROM FishOnLocation, ParamsFish, NamesFish, AkkFishTable
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 AS THE_ONE, FD_FISH_ID, FD_DTIME_ID FROM FishDaysTime) FDT0 ON (FD_FISH_ID=FL_FISH_ID AND FD_DTIME_ID=0)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 AS THE_ONE, FD_FISH_ID, FD_DTIME_ID FROM FishDaysTime) FDT1 ON (FD_FISH_ID=FL_FISH_ID AND FD_DTIME_ID=1)
...
WHERE FL_LOC_ID=76
AND PF_FISH_INDEX=NF_ID
AND FL_FISH_ID=PF_ID
AND AF_ID=NF_ID
```

Если подзапрос вернёт строку, то THE_ONE будет == 1
Если не вернёт ни шиша, то THE_ONE == NULL
COALECSE(...) Возвращает первый параметр, который != NULL.
В итоге получается 1, если есть строка в подзапрсе и 0, если её нет.

А на счёт dtype_unknown, может повыполнять все запросы, подзапросы, чтобы увидеть в каком из них получится колонка с непонятным типом? Консоль или ibexpert показывают тип колонки?

Answer (score 0):

Дайте имя столбцам `min(t1.PV_MIN_WEIGHT)` и `max(t1.PV_MAX_WEIGHT)`.

Comment: дал, это никак не влияет на результат

Comment: Если есть сортировка, уберите - в представлении не должно быть ORDER BY.

Comment: Вы же видите, что нету, в том то и дело... Может на `GROUP BY` такая же реакция?

Comment: Я вижу запрос, но не вижу представления.

Comment: @Isaev Зачем Вам нужна таблица t2 и левое соединение? Вы же из нее ничего не выбираете.

Comment: @BuilderC, Мне сложно сейчас точно вспомнить зачем, подумал даже может она в процессе разработки самоисключилась, но видимо неспроста... Но если я убераю `JOIN` и t2 меняю на t1 везде, то получаю неправильные значенияв полях `MIN` и `CREDIT`. В последнем некоторые значения обнулены, а первое вообще не правильно всё